# Ensure MySQL table charset & collation

Tags: mysql

Situation: there's a table that is managed by application A. Application A inserts and updates data in the table throughout the day. Once per week it `DROP`s the table, recreates it, and inserts all data.

Problem: application A creates the table as `utf8`. Application B that relies on this table require for it to be `ascii_bin`. I did not design either application, nor do I have access to modifying their requirements.

What's needed: a way to ensure that the table is in `ascii_bin`. I considered writing a script and run it via CRON, which would check the current charset and set it if needed. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Since `ALTER` is one of the statements that causes an implicit `COMMIT`, I do not believe it is possible to do it as part of a trigger after `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `ascii_bin` as a default charset for your database schema. Then all the created tables will have this charset when created, unless you explicitly specify another charset.

Refer to MySQL documentation on how to set the default charset: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that application A explicitly sets utf8 as part of its CREATE statement.

Comment: Well, then you'll have to change it manually once the table is created. A cron script sounds like an ok workaround.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy) might be a solution here.

You can rewrite the create statement when it goes through the proxy.

Alternatively, maybe you could remove privileges from Application A so it can't drop the table.

An ALTER statement that makes no changes is basically ignored. So, if the conversion to ascii_bin is run multiple times, it's not going to be much effort on the server. So, putting it in cron, or an exiting stored procedure that Applicatio B calls, or something else clever, isn't so bad.

Comment: Rewriting the DROP TABLE to a TRUNCATE and ignoring the CREATE TABLE completely would seem to be sensible.  Then there would be no need to run a cleanup ALTER.

Answer (score 0):

See SET NAME at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html